# How to chain Predicate<T> in filter() while using method references?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream, predicate

I have a class Movie like this:

```
public class Movie {    
    private int id, duration, publishingYear;
    private String title, translation;


    public Movie(int id, int duration, int publishingYear, String title, String translation) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.publishingYear = publishingYear;
        this.title = title;
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public Predicate<Movie> titleFilter(String filter){
        return m -> m.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
    }

    public Predicate<Movie> translationFilter(String filter){
        return m -> m.getTranslation().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

How to chain Predicate filters while using method references? I understand that method references can be seen as shorthand for lambdas calling only a specific method. In book I'm reading, it says: "...method reference lets you create a lambda expression from an existing method implementation...". So, why I can't do this?

```
ArrayList<Movie> filteredMovies = (ArrayList<Movie>) app.getMovies().stream()
                .filter((Movie::titleFilter(titleFilter)).or(Movie::translationFilter(translationFilter)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get that this will work:

```
Predicate<Movie> titlePredicate = ( m -> m.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(titleFilter)); 

Predicate<Movie> translationPredicate = ( m -> m.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(translationFilter)); 

ArrayList<Movie> filteredMovies = (ArrayList<Movie>) app.getMovies().stream()
                                    .filter(titlePredicate.or(translationPredicate))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As well as this (just insert into filter() ):

```
public boolean tFilter(String filter){
        return this.getTranslation().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
    }
```

I've recently started with lambdas and Stream API. In our curriculum at university there's no mention of streams. So I recon I start by myself. Newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because this:

```
Movie::titleFilter(titleFilter)
```

isn't really a method reference. You are kind of passing in a parameter, which seems to indicate that you want to *call* the method. But you are using `::`, which makes it look like a method references.

If you just did `Movie::titleFilter` however, that would be a method reference, but it can't be converted to `Predicate<Movie>`. It could be converted to `Function<String, Predicate<Movie>>` if you had specified the type explicitly, but that's obviously not what you want.

Also note that even if you had two methods in `Movie` like this (these are both convertible to `Predicate<Movie>`):

```
public boolean predicate1() { ... }

public boolean predicate2() { ... }
```

You cannot `or` them like this:

```
Movie::predicate1.or(Movie::predicate2)
```

Because `Movie::predicate1` doesn't have a type in and of itself. This is to allow it to be converted to any functional interface with a compatible signature. You have to do:

```
((Predicate<Movie>)Movie::predicate1).or(Movie::predicate2)
```

instead.

What I think you intended is:

```
// note the static modifiers
public static Predicate<Movie> titleFilter(String filter){
    return m -> m.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
}

public static Predicate<Movie> translationFilter(String filter){
    return m -> m.getTranslation().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase());
}
```

And:

```
// note that I am calling the methods which *return* a Predicate<Movie>
ArrayList<Movie> filteredMovies = (ArrayList<Movie>) app.getMovies().stream()
                .filter((Movie.titleFilter(titleFilter)).or(Movie.translationFilter(translationFilter)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically, to make a method reference, you can't pass parameters to it, and there's not such thing as "partial application" of a method in Java. (It'd be cool if it existed though...)

Comment: "Because Movie::predicate1 doesn't have a type in and of itself". Did you want to say this won't work because predicate1() doesn't represent "instance" of Functional Interface, that is, it's not lambda?

Comment: @MiljanPuletic Your wording is a bit different but I think you get the idea. Basically, I could create my own functional interface `interface Foo { boolean f(Movie m); }`, and `Movie::predicate1` could be converted to `Foo` as well, couldn't it? That's why method references don't have a type themselves. Lambdas don't have a type themselves either. Their types are inferred with the help of the clues you give to the compiler.

Comment: If I'm correct (and you will correct me), it could, but only if predicate1() returns lambda which has same signature as functional descriptor in Foo interface. And yeah, my wording sucks :)

Comment: @MiljanPuletic it’s not about what lambda the method returns, it’s about the whole signature of the method. `Movie::predicate1` can always be converted to `Foo` because it accepts a movie as a parameter and returns a boolean, which matches the requirement of `Foo`. At the same time, it can be converted to `Predicate<Movie>` because their signatures also match. This is why I said method references and lambdas don’t inherently have a type.

Comment: Thank you professor Sweeper. I know understand better.